# jQuery Masonry: repositon dom elements regardless of dom order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-masonry

this is the first time I'm working with the jQuery [Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

The problem I have is that I'm working with two sizes of `.box`es. So there is a basic size of `180x120px` and double the size of `360x240px``

And in order to explain my problem I made quick mockup of the site i'm currently working on.

[image]

What you can see here is the grid I have that is already working with masonry. The numbers in the boxes represent the order of the boxes in the DOM.

As you can see there is a "space" missing in the upper right corner since DOM-element nr5 is a large box.

**Now my question**
Is it possible (or is there a setting for masonry) so that in this case Nr.7 would float to the upper right corner? I just don't want to have any spaces left!

Any ideas?

The code I'm working with is this …

```
$wall.masonry({ 
          columnWidth: 180, 
          itemSelector: '.box:not(.invis)',
          animate: true,
            animationOptions: {
              duration: 650,
              easing: 'linear',
              singleMode: true,
              queue: true
            }
        });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the wookmark jquery plugin if it fix your problem. The wookmark plugin is the same like masonry and it's also using a bin-packing algorithm. But I don't think the masonry plugin waste space because there is too many combinations. It's a np complete or hard problem. When you can solve it in polynominal time you are a rich man!?